# Limit on modulus lines in OpenSSH /etc/ssh/moduli file?

Tags: key-exchange, diffie-hellman, openssh

I understand that OpenSSH server looks in `/etc/ssh/moduli` and picks a modulus at random for each Diffie-Hellman group exchange.  What I am wondering is whether there is a practical limit on how many modulus lines can be in that file.

Would an absurdly large number, such as 50,000 lines, pose a problem or create some weird behavior?

Answer (score 1):

**Most likely 4294967295.**

In the source file `dh.c`, the moduli file is opened with `fopen`, and a `fgets` loop is used to extract each line. The current line being processed is recorded in a variable declared as `int linenum`. This means it is a 32 bit signed integer, capable of representing 2<sup>32</sup> possible values. Since it is signed, this equates to -2147483648 to 2147483647 (one less because 0 is still a number and is considered positive). Since it starts at 0 and increments, the maximum value is thus 2<sup>32</sup> / 2 - 1. It will become negative if it exceeds this bound and wraps around.

There is some conversion between signed and unsigned in the source code. The `int linenum` holds the number of lines, while `int bestcount` has the number of suitable lines and is passed to `arc4random_uniform`, which outputs a random value between 0 and `bestcount`. The value it accepts and the value it returns is unsigned, but it is stored in another signed integer, `which`. That integer is used to specify which random line is to be used. If the number of lines exceeds what an 32 bit integer can hold, the random choice of line's upper bound will be smaller, perhaps much smaller, than the actual number of lines.

This limitation is not an issue in practice. The maximum length of a line is 4096 bytes, and 2<sup>32</sup> lines (not - 1 because the first line starts at 0) of 4096 bytes each gives a maximum file size of 16 terabytes! Good luck waiting for openssl dhparam to generate terabytes of moduli.

The whole function in the source code, as of OpenSSH 7.5p1:

```
DH *
choose_dh(int min, int wantbits, int max)
{
    FILE *f;
    char line[4096];
    int best, bestcount, which;
    int linenum;
    struct dhgroup dhg;

    if ((f = fopen(_PATH_DH_MODULI, "r")) == NULL) {
        logit("WARNING: could not open %s (%s), using fixed modulus",
            _PATH_DH_MODULI, strerror(errno));
        return (dh_new_group_fallback(max));
    }

    linenum = 0;
    best = bestcount = 0;
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), f)) {
        linenum++;
        if (!parse_prime(linenum, line, &dhg))
            continue;
        BN_clear_free(dhg.g);
        BN_clear_free(dhg.p);

        if (dhg.size > max || dhg.size < min)
            continue;

        if ((dhg.size > wantbits && dhg.size < best) ||
            (dhg.size > best && best < wantbits)) {
            best = dhg.size;
            bestcount = 0;
        }
        if (dhg.size == best)
            bestcount++;
    }
    rewind(f);

    if (bestcount == 0) {
        fclose(f);
        logit("WARNING: no suitable primes in %s", _PATH_DH_MODULI);
        return (dh_new_group_fallback(max));
    }

    linenum = 0;
    which = arc4random_uniform(bestcount);
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), f)) {
        if (!parse_prime(linenum, line, &dhg))
            continue;
        if ((dhg.size > max || dhg.size < min) ||
            dhg.size != best ||
            linenum++ != which) {
            BN_clear_free(dhg.g);
            BN_clear_free(dhg.p);
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
    fclose(f);
    if (linenum != which+1) {
        logit("WARNING: line %d disappeared in %s, giving up",
            which, _PATH_DH_MODULI);
        return (dh_new_group_fallback(max));
    }

    return (dh_new_group(dhg.g, dhg.p));
}
```

Note that this is all from a cursory glance at the source code. If there are other issues that may occur down the line for reasons I can't predict caused by a large file, the upper limit may be smaller. I don't see any reason to think it would be, though.